# Find and validate all automapper mappings

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to be able to traverse an assembly for each type that is mapped as a source (or destination), and verify that the mapping configuration is valid.  This is for a rather large project that uses AutoMapper extensively and I'd like this unit test to break when a dev introduces an invalid mapping relationship.  Looking at collection of GetAllMappedTypes, GetPropertyMaps, but I don't seem to be able to get to a way to check for a valid configuration.  We're using v4 of AutoMapper.

Answer (score 3):

The automapper code for this is:

```
<Perform mapping configuration work>

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()
```

If you're using nunit, you can do:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class when_validating_mapping_config
    {
        [Test]
        public void then_should_assert_mapping_configuration_is_valid()
        {
            // Arrange
            MappingConfig.InitializeMappings(); // this is just however you initialize your mappings.

            // Act

            // Assert
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
```

The mappingconfig is just how I initialize my mappings. I am using automapper in MVC so all my static configuration happens in Global.asax.cs.

```
public static class MappingConfig
{
    public static void InitializeMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(configuration => Configure(configuration));
    }

    public static void Configure(IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        configuration.CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>()
        configuration.Seal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm missing something in the nUnit example you provide.  I do not see any type MappingConfig.  Can you help me fill in the blanks.  Should've mentioned, I'm learning AutoMapper on the go here.

Comment: I simplified the code and posted the mappingconfig I'm using.